What is the difference between "maximal Cauchy development" and "maximal global hyperbolic development" within General Relativity?
Following the theorem of Choquet-Bruhat and Geroch, we can define the maximal Cauchy development of initial data (see Theorem 10.2.2 of Wald's 1984 GR book, herewith attached). However, in the literature, I see "maximal global hyperbolic development" used interchangeably (at least, it seems that way to me?).
Can you please indicate the precise difference between "maximal Cauchy development" and "maximal global hyperbolic development"?

